# Keep getting error on UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I really have no idea on how to fix this problem! when I executed my model file I got an error on batch_index which I can't fix. I tried to google on this error but still haven't found any solution to this problem yet. Is there anything wrong with my code? Why it showed me that error? How can I fix it? Please help..

the error I got

```
if batch_index == len(batches) - 1:  # Last batch.
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment
```

lenet.py

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense, Flatten
from keras import backend as K


class LeNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        #initialize the model
        model = Sequential()
        inputShpage = (height, width, depth)

        # if we are using "channel first" update the input shape
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShpage = (depth, height, width)

        # first set of CONV => RELU => MaxPooling
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=inputShpage))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # second set of CONV => RELU => MaxPooling
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # FC => RELU layer
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(500))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # softmax classifier for probability
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model
```

model.py

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.utils import np_utils
from lenet import LeNet
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the argument
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help="path to the dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to the output model or saved model")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the list of data and label
data = []
labels = []

for imagePath in sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))):
    # load the image, preprocessing it and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)

    # extract the class label from the image path and update the labels list
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-3]
    label = "Hong" if label == "hong" else "Not Hong"
    labels.append(label)

    # scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0,1]
    data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
    label = np.array(labels)

    # convert labels from integers to vectors
    le = LabelEncoder().fit(labels)
    labels = np_utils.to_categorical(le.transform(labels), 2)

    # account for skew in the labeled data
    classTotals = labels.sum(axis=0)
    classWeight = classTotals.max() / classTotals

    # split the data into training_set and test_set
    (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, 
                                                    test_size=0.33, 
                                                    random_state=42)

    # initialize the model
    print("[ WORKING ON MODEL ] compiling model.....")
    model = LeNet.build(width=64, height=64, depth=3, classes=2)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

    # train the network
    print("[ WORKING ON NETWORK ] traning the network.....")
    H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
                class_weight=classWeight, batch_size=32, epochs=25, verbose=1)

    # evaluate the network
    print("[ WORKING ON NETWORK ] evaluating the network.....")
    predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=32)
    print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1),
                                target_names=le.classes_))

    # saving the model
    print("[ WORKING ON NETWORK ] serializing network.....")
    model.save(args["model"])
```

Comment: This is simple python issue, you have not initialized batch_index, and that part is not in any of the code you shared.  Please remove the the tensorflow, keras, and deep-learning tags as it dilutes search quality.

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) multiple times before. See duplicate question.